# URL Redirect In Redux Action With Server-Side React & React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, react-router-v4, server-side-rendering

I have been trying to figure out for a long time the best way to handle a redirect for a server-side rendered react app, using react-router v4 and redux.

My App fetches data from an API - sometimes the API responds in a way that makes me need to redirect the user to another URL automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API responds in a way that causes me to need to redirect, I store the path that the user should be directed to in the redux store. (My API returns an error object with a "redirect" variable I can lookup in my routes file to insert into the store as the redirect path).

Importantly, this is just storing the path in the redux store.

```js
case (typeof error["redirect"] !== "undefined" && error["redirect"] !== null): {
    dispatch({
        type: RENDER_REDIRECT,
        payload: routes[error["redirect"]]
    });
    break;
}
```

I have a component called "RenderRedirect", this component is always rendered in the main app, but takes special action if this.props shows the redirect as "null" and nextProps redirect as !null.

This means a redirect has been triggered.

It uses history.push to change the URL, and then clears the redirect out of the store using another action.

This works particularly well because I don't have to worry about server-side rendering erring, because this situation can only happen client-side.

Anytime I need to trigger a redirect I can easily dispatch the above action with a path as a payload.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { clearRedirect } from '../../../actions';

class RenderRedirect extends Component {

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // Detect redirect, perform redirect, clear redirect
        const { redirect, history, clearRedirectAction } = this.props;

        // Detect redirect
        if(redirect === null && nextProps.redirect !== null) {
            history.push(nextProps.redirect);
            clearRedirectAction();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { redirect } = this.props;

        if (redirect !== null) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p className={"profile-instructions"}>Redirecting...</p>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    redirect: state.redirect
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    clearRedirectAction: () => dispatch(clearRedirect())
})

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RenderRedirect));
```